# Strategy for finding cluster solution with positive values for Cubic Clustering Criterion

Tags: clustering, sas

I am trying to cluster a data set with approximately 3500 entries, consisting primarily of likert-10 scale survey answers.  Most of the survey answers are skewed - a typical example is below:

[image: distribution]

I've done the following:

- Range-standardized the data
- Removed rows where the survey respondent answered all questions with a 5/neutral or 10/strongly agree
- Used SAS's PROC VARCLUS and PROC FACTOR to reduce the variables used in the clustering solution
- Eliminated variables with the greatest skew
- Use the [TRIM=](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_cluster_sect004.htm) option to eliminate cluster outliers.

Despite all of this, all of my cluster solutions are consistently showing negative Cubic Clustering Criterion values.  Here is a typical example:
[image: Negative CCC]

Can anyone suggest a strategy for coming up with a cluster solution with positive CCC? I'm not sure what to try next.